# React-native to reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

I have 4 different IPad apps in react-native, that I need to convert quickly to nextJS to offer them as desktop as well. Exporting as webview is not an option, since in react-native they have API calls that require custom certificates and encryption.

Is there like a code scripting bot that can go through the project folder and convert the rendering part from react-native to reactJS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/). From my experience, **Webpack** is a better option than **Vite**. You will be able to use at least 80-90% of your react-native code base on the web, some components like **TextInput** or **Image** are not supported in that case you just create your web version like **Image.web.tsx**. You can also wrap it in an **Electron** container.